# Front USB not working

Tags: usb, motherboard

My computer has 2 front USB ports, one of them works and one doesn't. I don't know if it isn't plugged in or some other problem, here is what I think should be plugged in. I appreciate that these cables may be unrelated or completely generic, but all help appreciated.

[image: these cables?]
[image: go in here?]

Comment: The AC'97 one is audio. The other is a case USB port. You can plug it into a motherboard USB connector. Make sure it's in the right way. Usually there are two ports per connector like [this](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/wp-content/uploads/manual-placa1.gif). Anyway, refer to your **motherboard manual** (download it if you have lost it) and your **case manual** (ditto) though the latter is often less helpful.

Comment: Add that as an answer and I'll up it! That worked a treat, both ports are working now, thanks @SpheroPefhany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AC'97 one is audio. The other is a case USB port. You can plug it into a motherboard USB connector. Make sure it's in the right way. Usually there are two ports per connector like [this](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/wp-content/uploads/manual-placa1.gif). Anyway, refer to your **motherboard manual** (download it if you have lost it) and your **case manual** (ditto) though the latter is often less helpful.

In the future these questions are better in another SE (superuser, I think, is the right one).